# how to convert multiple mysql result sets into json array

Tags: php, json, arrays

i am executing multiple "select" statements in my php script. Then I am adding them to array by `$Output=array($out, $out1);` and then encoding it by `json_encode()`

the output is coming in format `[ [{},{}] , [{}, {}] ]`

how do i convert it in form - `{"str1": [{},{}], "str2": [{},{}]}`

**php script:**

```
<?php

require 'DbConnect.php';


$query = ("SELECT * FROM `cars`");
$query1 = ("SELECT * FROM `City`");

if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)){

while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){

    $out [] = $query_row;

}

}else{
    echo 'Fail';
} 

//second query 

if ($query_run1 = mysql_query($query1)){

while ($query_row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run1)){

$out1 [] = $query_row1;

}

}else{
    echo 'Fail';
} 

$Output=array($out, $out1); 
echo(json_encode($Output));
?>
```

Comment: ok, so plz tel me how should i encode it?

Comment: [ [{},{}] , [{}, {}] ] is ur output ...but before encoding put it in array

Comment: Hi @Pooja my code is not useful for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are getting result in  `[ [{},{}] , [{}, {}] ]`

then try

```
$Output=array('str1'=>$out,'str2'=>$out1); 
  echo(json_encode($Output,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $query = "SELECT 
    post_title, 
    guid 
    FROM testwp_posts
    WHERE 
    post_author = $user_id 
    AND
    post_status = 'publish' 
    ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $number_of_posts";

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Errant query:  '.$query);

        /* create one master array of the records */
        $posts = array();
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
            while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
            }
        }


            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));
```

Comment: wat is $link in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require 'DbConnect.php';


$query = ("SELECT * FROM `cars`");
$query1 = ("SELECT * FROM `City`");

if ($query_run = mysql_query($query))
{
    while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
    {   
        $output['cars'][] = $query_row;
    }

}
else
{
    echo 'Fail';
} 

//second query 

if ($query_run1 = mysql_query($query1))
{
    while ($query_row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run1))
    {
        $output['city'][] = $query_row1;
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Fail';
} 

echo(json_encode($output));
?>
```

may it helps

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps your requirement, but try below things..

Instead of using

```
$out [] = $query_row;
```

Use

```
$out['str1'][] = $query_row;
```

AND Instead of

```
$out1 [] = $query_row1;
```

Use

```
$out['str2'][] = $query_row1;
```

And now try this

```
echo(json_encode($out));
```